# How can I improve my question about problems rendering VBOs in OpenGL?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, asking-questions

Recently I have been active, and on my latest post I just received 2 downvotes. Not a big deal but it got me thinking, my questions never get upvotes, even though I provide my research, relevant code, a GitHub with the project, etc.

Here's the post I am talking about:
[OpenGL VBOs not rendering to the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54601707/opengl-vbos-not-rendering-to-the-screen); you can tell I spent 30 minutes researching it, and it got no upvotes.

Yet when I search by newest, I see things like this:
[AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'counter'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54640238/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-counter); no time has been put into the question, and yet it still gets upvotes.

Is this just a fluke, or am I doing something wrong with my posts?

Comment: Well your question currently has three close votes for: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: Tricky thing here is I'm not sure what would qualify as "minimum" code to reproduce an OpenGL question, and I'm willing to bet that *some* people may have been intimidated by the volume of code you had to present.  If you feel reasonably comfortable with the amount of code that you've posted - in that it *truly* is minimal - then... I suppose this is really a hollow consolation in that the site doesn't really know what to do in those scenarios.  If it *isn't* minimal, that's at least something you can move towards.

Comment: With OpenGL, theres a ton of hoops you need to jump through to render basic quads. I included all code I feel relevant. I have 3 methods, swtup for rendering, rendering, and flushing the data, I don’t include setting vertex attributes, making the window, etc... And Servey, I feel that it is pretty obvious I am trying to draw a textured quad from the line “The screen color is set, but nothing is drawing.” and since it is OpenGL, I have no idea which line is causing the texture to not draw. Thats why there are so many generic OpenGL questions.

Comment: Right - this is where our cookie-cutter advice falls short.  I think you're hit with some bad luck here in that the people looking at your question don't believe it fits the right pattern of "minimal".  Maybe someone with OpenGL expertise can weigh in on the quality of the question, since I'm sure out of my league here...

Comment: I emproved my question to make it more clear, I do see how it was kind of vague, but what I was asking was still pretty clear, even if it wasn’t as professional as I would like.

Comment: One thing you mention here is that "you can tell I spent 30 minutes researching it". I... honestly can't. The biggest body of your question is to explain your code, what's happening, what you want to see happen (that's **good**). The only thing from the question talking about research is "I found glDrawElements(), but not sure if it would help". Research is subjective, but this seems a bit along the line of "I found this method, but I don't want to try it". I wouldn't have downvoted that question though, it seems on point.

Comment: glDrawElements() is made for meshes, and I said I think it’s not relevant because I’m drawing a single quad. I did try it but nothing changed because something else is causing nothing to draw.

Comment: "30 minutes" :) - please check out https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Comment: @Big_Bad but see, saying 'I found it and tried it, and it doesn't work because I am not drawing a mesh' is very different than what I saw in your question, which was 'I found that that may help, but I don't think it does, so I haven't tried'. You have to be more explicit than you think. People don't know what you've done prior to opening your Q.

Comment: Yes I see now that I am going back over it, but still doesn't seem like that bad of a question. I can improve it but I think it's good for me only posting 12 questions (not including this one). Definitely not something I want my account blocked from posting questions over (I have been notified when posting my last 2 questions that if I ask any more questions which receive 0 or negative upvotes, my account will be blocked from asking questions). Also @AlexeiLevenkov note this was after I wrote all this code. That was 30 minutes + writing the code + other failed attempts.

Comment: Just a general tip: be aware that java-gaming.org exists, the site where Java game developers like to hang out. Java game dev has always been kind of niche so I find it works best if you go to where they are rather than go to Stack Overflow and hope they find you ;)

Comment: Did not know that site exists, I’ll go check it out.

Comment: RE: [MCVEs](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), takes about [120 lines of C++ using GLFW](https://pastebin.com/hqKPHd8C) to load shaders, create geometry, and render to screen.  I strongly suspect something similar is possible in Java in about the same space.

Comment: There is no such thing as a stupid question, imho.

Comment: Don't (just) clarify in the comments. If there's a point that is worth you responding in a comment you should go back and edit your post. In particular, if you want help with a problem, "hook" the reader with an easily-scanned list of things you have tried and symptoms observed (you may find your own answer whilst editing your question). As an example of a difficult issue with a lot of research, where I was completely lost, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153330/numeric-code-porting-powerpc-to-intel-gives-different-results-using-float

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Honestly... Your question is decent. About the only thing you can do to improve it is to *keep debugging:*

1. Look at [similar problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52166279/lwjgl-gldrawarrays-doesnt-draw) and their solutions; see what applies and what doesn't. Keep notes on what you've learned in your question.
2. Find a [tutorial](http://wiki.lwjgl.org/wiki/The_Quad_with_DrawArrays.html) and verify that you can follow it and run the result successfully on your platform. Make a note of this in your question as well.
3. Start adapting the tutorial to include functionality from your program. Make note of when things fall apart (in your question also please).
4. When you've identified the specific bit of your program that isn't working, make a note of *that*.

Naturally, getting to #4 is going to take a bit. But, #4 will also give you probably the single biggest improvement you can make to your question: **a title that's more interesting than "not rendering to the screen"**. To be clear, it's not your fault that you don't have a better title right now... You haven't done steps #1 through #3 yet. But you should realize: folks who hang out in the graphics-oriented sections of Stack Overflow see a *lot* of questions whose titles boil down to, "I tried X, but X isn't appearing" - it's effectively the same as saying, "my code doesn't work", and every bit as boring.

Nobody likes to be bored. The more specific & detailed you can be about where you're having trouble, the more likely you'll catch someone's interest & get a useful answer.

Comment: Yeah the title was dumb, I was feeling a bit flustered when I wrote the thing. I've just thrown everything out and restarted by adapting code from a tutorial.

Comment: How can we add this in the "How to ask?" section on the help center? I mean, I'm sure you can infer it (heck, I'm sure is there) but maybe an ordered list would be more digestible?

Comment: Sorry, but I completely disagree. The question lacks at least the shaders. It doesn't show which data is draw. How should we know the geometry is not simply outside the viewport? It's not minimal: it is also nothing drawn when no textures are used. So why show the texture code. There is also a lot of unused code present (for example element buffer although gldrawarrays). I can write a more complete answer here later on, but in the current state it is impossible to answer the question in any meaningful way.

Comment: Honestly, ever single opengl question that boils down to "I see nothing" and doesn't show their shaders, data and matrices should be closed instantly.

Comment: You should definitely write an answer, @BDL!

Comment: @Shog9 My bad, I just assumed you meant on the actual question "write an answer"

Comment: BDL was suggesting that they could write an answer here later on, and I was encouraging them to do so. Context matters ;-)

Comment: I say in the comments I tested the shaders, and the images are loded using STB which I just left in the github because I checked them and know the image loads correctly. I posted the methods I know are causing the problem, the rest I have tested in a separate project using OpenGL 2.2. I did not know glDrawArrays doesn’t draw the EBO, and I figured that out recently and I am trying to revise the code.

Answer (score 5):

People who don't know OpenGL and Java may think this looks like a good question but as someone who has the capability of actually answering what you have, this question just puts so much work on the part of the answerer it A: isn't worth answering, and B: makes it too broad to deal with in its current form.

- One gigantic issue is that I can't just download the libraries you used, take your code, and run this.  Why?  Because the vast majority of your code is behind that link to your github repository... You don't even include your shaders, which could be were the problem is in the first place! What you have is not a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

  **[image: strong text]**

  So now I'm going to have to download a bunch of code off your github, and if you reorganize it or fix your issue on your own, it could be impossible to answer because now I need to find the specific commit you used. Or the whole repo could go private, be deleted or disappear in some other way.
- A second issue is that even if I *did* go and download your code and try to run everything, *what you have on github is not an MVCE*.  There is way too much code there to just draw a quad on screen.

  You've got all this setup code, game stuff, and all together irrelevant stuff to just doing what you claim to be "just trying to do", which is apparently to draw a quad to the screen.  Besides the framebuffer callback, how are the other callbacks necessary? You've got this syncing thread code for manual vsync (not shown on SO) which isn't necessary for drawing quads, and bugs could hide in that (like some how stalling the drawing thread).

  You could argue "well if I get rid of that code than maybe this issue won't be reproduced" and we would say "Great! Problem solved". Now you can figure out what actually causes this issue on your own, or provide the function that potentially causes this issue in a SO question if you can't, and save us a few hundred potentially irrelevant lines we would have to read otherwise.
- The final issue is this question becomes useless to SO because of the two previous issues.  If someone has the same problem as you, what ever that is, there's no way they can tell by looking at the question right now, its not complete so they can't run it on their own, and it isn't minimal, so another beginner won't be able to understand it on their own.  Questions and answers are meant to help other people with your same or similar problems, but when it becomes impossible to decipher whether or not you had a close enough issue, it becomes useless.

Go back, create a new file that *only* does what is necessary to produce a quad, then if that doesn't work, come back with that minimal example to show us, and show *all the code*.

Comment: @Big_Bad_E "using OpenGl 2.4" well that is new... "Trying to find a LWJGL 3d tutorial but everything uses glVertex3f() and glDraw(), which I’m pretty sure isn’t supported in **OpenGL 3.2**", you seemed to indicate you were using OpenGL 3.2, and your Github code only mentions 3.2 and if that isn't available use 2.1...  Regardless you haven't alleviated or addressed anything in my answer, there isn't a negotiation on this, if you want your question properly answered, you need to do the work to write a MVCE.

Comment: Well a few things: I know I am missing a method, I have tested the shaders using OpenGL 2.4, the repo is maven so you don’t need to hunt down all the libraries I use. Also, the only extra thing in there is input handling, which is 4 extra classes in another package. While syncing the FPS to the monitor’s fps isn’t needed, It’s one if statement and 2 fields. I removed all my extra code from another post I made, where I realized it wasn’t minimal. So that invalidates points 1, 2, and 3. Yes I did not mention I tested the shaders in the post, but I do in the second comment.

Comment: @Big_Bad_E While the lack of mention of dependencies in your post is a big problem, I didn't talk about that, I talked about even in the situation where I assume I could just get all the libraries you used with out looking at your github page it is way too much effort to answer.  And btw, you still haven't fixed anything we talked about.  You can get all the upvotes you want, but until you actually fix your post with a true MVCE, you aren't going to get the answer you want in a reasonable timeframe.

Comment: What do you mean the lack of dependencies is a big problem, the only time they are needed is if the code is downloaded, and I have maven so they are automatically downloaded. I fixed my GitHub and made it a MCVE, and the methods I have highlighted are the problematic methods. I have not "harassed" any users on meta, I have asked what I think is a valid question on how to improve the quality of my questions, and I am, I have answered every comment and answer that I have, and I made my GitHub an MVCE in the spare time I have. I will update the code in the question.